# SignalR/Hubs for Jabbr gives 404 Error

Tags: c#, signalr

I have two Projects; MVC 4 and JabbR (WebForms). I'm doing integration release, so I added JabbR as a reference in my MVC 4 Project. And I wrote batch file to copy all marckups to my project and bring the configurations, everything is great till now.

Now, I tried to run the app. But signalr/hubs is not available. i'm using IIS 8.
Cannot detect the problem!!! Why!?

I also checked the FAQ in https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq

Nothing happend?!?!?! :( please help

Comment: Have you added the signalr javascript file as a reference? For example: jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js

Comment: Yeah I did .. And it gives me error in browser for "~/signalr/hubs" reference only
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalR")
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Question answered Here in this link

https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR/issues/599

> "JabbR is a standalone application. It is not meant to be integrated in the
>   way that you described above" by samandmoore